# How to harden user/login password?

Tags: password

In High Sierra or Mojave, is it possible to harden our login password so that the hash is more difficult to crack? I'm not a crypto person, but can we increase the iterations, transforms, hashing algo strenth or something... to make the CPU work harder when using sudo and such? I know [Debian/Ubuntu distros are capable of such hardening](https://www.slashroot.in/how-are-passwords-stored-linux-understanding-hashing-shadow-utils) and [keepass has a similar feature](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83900/). Is it possible in macOS?

Comment: Longer passwords make them harder to crack.

Comment: This is more of a MacOS config question than a security question.

Comment: Is your intent to modify the operating system or just program your apps to salt and iterate more slowly?

Answer (score 3):

On MacOS you can use PBKD2 (Password Based Key Derivation 2) to create secure password verifiers. This is an accepted method by NIST. Supply a random salt (you can save it with the hashed password) and an iteration count such the the derivation takes around 100ms.

When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial time finding passwords by brute force.

See [NIST Digital Identity Guidelines](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf)

See this [How to use CommonCrypto for PBKDF2 in Swift 2 & 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40342300/451475)
 or example code.